# Matlab regexp command not working as intended

Tags: regex, matlab, directory

```
f =  dir('../Data/PML*.mat');
f1 = regexp({f.name}, 'PML*.mat', 'match');
[f1{:}]
```

This is the snippet of my code to select files in the Data folder residing in the parent directory. The f is a structure array of 66 elements(There are 66 files there) as expected and out of these I want to select files which have a filename as follows:
`PMLsigma_8PMLkappa_6.mat`. However the result of these operations is an empty cell array and I have no idea it results in an empty array. If instead of `'PML*.mat'` on the second line -in the definition of f1- I write the full file name then there are no problems. What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT**: First two elements of {f.name} cell array

r =

```
'PMLsigma_10PMLkappa_1.mat'    'PMLsigma_10PMLkappa_2.mat'
```

Comment: Please provide a sample of `f.name`

Comment: @excaza I have added the first two strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest going through MATLAB's [regexp documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) again, paying particular attention to the [`expression`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html#inputarg_expression) portion.

Your regex expression `'PML*.mat'` is attempting to match files that follow the below criteria:

1. (`PM`) Match `PM` exactly
2. (`L*`) Match `L` between 0 and unlimited times
3. (`.`) Match any single character
4. (`mat`) Match `mat` exactly

Matching strings include: `PML.mat`, `PMkmat`, and `PMLLLLLLLLLLLLLLL.mat`

One functional alternative could be `'PML.*\.mat'`, which operates as follows:

1. (`PML`) Match `PML` exactly
2. (`.*`) Match any character between 0 and unlimited times
3. (`\.`) Match `.` exactly (`\` is an [escape character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character))
4. (`mat`) Match `mat` exactly

As an aside, if you're already filtering the results in your `dir` call, why do you need `regexp`?

Comment: Sometimes I do a finer filtering of the file names and that is why I have regular expressions in my code. I was thinking that regular expressions worked as they worked in the `dir` command. Although I checked the documentation I did not notice this subtlety. Thanks